# Determine how much of a component is visible on screen

Tags: codenameone

I'd like to know how much of a component is visible on the display.
Ideally there was a method Component.getVisibleBounds() returning the intersection of the components bounds and the visible rectangle or null if it is not visible at all - which could be the case if the parent container is scrollable and only part of the parent container is scrolled into view.

This should be possible because the Container class supports things like the method getComponentAt and it apparently even optimizes painting children by determining which components are visible. But I seem to have trouble figuring out how I can calculate the visible rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

When painting we use the clipping bounds to determine the visible area and reduce/eliminate unnecessary paint calls. This is crucial for fast performance.

During the paint process we don't really know what's visible and what isn't, just clipping. So a component might be obscured or scrolled halfway down and we won't know at this stage.